# how can i reduce the duplication in these methods

Tags: c#, optimization

Consider the following method:

```
    private bool DescriptionValid(Membership membership, string identifier)
    {
    // search for identifier in 4 lists
    // only need to find it failing in one

    if (membership.premium.Where(ev => ev.Id == identifier).Any())
    {
        var ev = membership.premium.Where(x => x.Id == identifier).Select(m => m).SingleOrDefault();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ev.Remarks))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (membership.club.Where(ev => ev.Id == identifier).Any())
    {
        var ev = membership.club.Where(x => x.Id == identifier).Select(m => m).SingleOrDefault();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ev.Remarks))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (membership.basic.Where(ev => ev.Id == identifier).Any())
    {
        var ev = membership.basic.Where(x => x.Id == identifier).Select(m => m).SingleOrDefault();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ev.Remarks))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (membership.junior.Where(ev => ev.Id == identifier).Any())
    {
        var ev = membership.junior.Where(x => x.Id == identifier).Select(m => m).SingleOrDefault();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ev.Remarks))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // no fails
    return true;
}
```

Membership is a property which contains four lists:

```
public IList<PremiumMemberShip> premium { get; set; } = new List<PremiumMemberShip>();

public IList<ClubMemberShip> club { get; set; } = new List<ClubMemberShip>();

public IList<BasicMemberShip> basic { get; set; } = new List<BasicMemberShip>();

public IList<JuniorMemberShip> junior { get; set; } = new List<JuniorMemberShip>();
```

Each membership is different, but they share similar traits. 
Is there a way I can condense the code below?
Essentially the same property is being tested each time, it's just that the type is changing for the different `if`s.

It feels like there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: You don’t need `.Any()`, you can just test if `.SingleIrDefault()` returns `null`.

Comment: This question is more suitable for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Make sure to follow their [recommendations](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: "Each membership is different, but they share similar traits" - do they share a base class or interface? Can you post the full class definitions?

Comment: I think you should use a basic MemberShip class and then derive the other specialzed variants from that.

Comment: Use a common interface.

Comment: Do all those different membership classes all implement an interface or inherit a base class that has `Remarks`, and are the `.club`, `.basic` and `.junior` objects all derived from a class or implement an interface that has an `Id` property?

Comment: @Vlad As optimization ev=>... should be in Any()

Comment: @Vlad: Why so complicated? .Any() is exactly meant for this purpose.

Comment: @Robert: because it’s an unnecessary LINQ call, so it’s inefficient. Much simpler is `var ev = list.Where(...).SingleOrDefault(); if (ev != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(ev.Remarks)) return false;`

Comment: @Vlad The `Where` clause `Followed by `SingleOrDefault` can be simplified as well of course by simply using `FirstOrDefault(ev => ev.Id == identifier)`. And the following  `if` can simply be `return ev == null || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ev.Remarks)`

Comment: @oerkelens: good point about Where. But the if simplification isn’t quite good: the code would never check the remaining lists

Comment: @Vlad, no, the `if` doesn't work in this case. I was thinking of a scenario where one would use a function acting on the base class of those `Membership`s :)

Comment: I am tooo tired to type it, but I would probably merge the 4 lists into a dictionary (id, remarks) and just check that for a failure.

Comment: @oerkelens: yeah, I see your point. This way one can just use `return f(list1) && f(list2) && ...`

Comment: @ChristianSauer: it’s not clear if a single Id is allowed to appear in several lists.

Comment: @MatthewWatson no, they don't.... they inherit from several other classes but they do share common properties... `id` and `remarks` being two of them. I understand they could each implement the same interface...?

Comment: @Vlad the id will only be in one list

Comment: @dstewart101: Same interface is good, too

Comment: @dstewart101: if so, you could Concat all the lists and have just one check on the concatenated list: `var ev = list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list3).Concat(list4).SingleOrDefault(ev.Id == id); return ev == null || string.IsNullOrWhitespace(ev.Comment);`

Comment: But you’ll need to cast to `IEnumerable<common interface here>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without changing any of the structure of you code you could always just do this:

```
private bool DescriptionValid(Membership membership, string identifier)
{
    var query =
        from ms in new []
        {
            membership.premium.Select(m => new { m.Id, m.Remarks }),
            membership.club.Select(m => new { m.Id, m.Remarks }),
            membership.basic.Select(m => new { m.Id, m.Remarks }),
            membership.junior.Select(m => new { m.Id, m.Remarks }),
        }
        let ev = ms.Where(x => x.Id == identifier).SingleOrDefault()
        where ev != null && String.IsNullOrEmpty(ev.Remarks)
        select ev;

    return !query.Any();
}
```

Comment: wow. ok! i'll try this. i have tests to back this code up so i can make changes easily enough to try.

Comment: There's a couple of differences here though. I can't say if it matters in the specific case, but the original code allows for opting out early. This implementation always go through all the iterations and allocates a new array on top of that.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen - No, it stops on the first one that produces a value automatically - no different to the OP's code. Allocating an array of four reference values is negligible in the scheme of things.

Comment: Am I missing something? Won't the four Selects be evaluated when you do Where on `ms`? And the problem is not allocating four refs, but possibly triggering GC.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen - No, each `ms` is evaluated one at a time and since LINQ is lazy as soon as the first `select ev` gets hit the `query.Any()` completes.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen - The 16 bytes for the array is probably not the thing that triggers the GC.

Comment: Okay, I need to look closer at the evaluation then. Thanks for clarifying. GC is triggered when the budget for gen 0 is exhausted. An array with four elements (which is a bit more than 16 bytes, but that's not the point) can easily do that. If this is not run in a tight loop there's probably nothing to be concerned about, but for tight loops allocations are bad no matter the size.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can create common code by keeping the commonalities and abstracting from the differences. Create a helper method:

1. The source collection (`membership.premium`) becomes a method argument.
2. The `return false;` becomes a return type of `bool`.
3. The classes (`PremiumMemberShip`, ...) must expose a common API surface to the helper. This can be done in various ways:

   1. An interface with `Id` and `Remarks` members.
   2. A common base class.
   3. `dynamic`.
   4. The helper method could be generic and take functions `Func<T, int> getID, Func<T, string> getRemarks`.

Otherwise, the helper method contains a copy of the existing code with fairly mechanical changes.